# Understanding Firebase ValueEventListeners onDataChange()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I went through the documentation about how to retrieve datain Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

In my firebase app I am retrieving the values using the addListenerForSingleValueEvent.
Those values retrieved(here **userIdKey**) in the onDataChange method are used to make updates to some other places in the database.

What I have observed is that sometimes the updates are made everywhere except 
at **123** (refer the code below).

```
    DatabaseReference channelFollowersRef = mDatabase.child("followers").child(mKey);
    channelFollowersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String userIdKey=childSnapshot.getKey();
        /*123*/ delChannelMap.put("/user-subscriptions/" + userIdKey + "//" + mChannelKey,null);
            }

            delChannelMap.put("/channels/" + mChannelKey, null);
            delChannelMap.put("/user-channels/" + getUid() + "/" + mChannelKey, null);
            delChannelMap.put("/channels-notices/" + mChannelKey, null);
            delChannelMap.put("/channels-subChannels/" + mChannelKey, null);
            delChannelMap.put("/channels-subChannels-comments/" + mChannelKey, null);
            delChannelMap.put("/channel-followers/" + mChannelKey, null);

            mDatabase.updateChildren(delChannelMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChannelDetailActivity.this, "Channel is now deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

How to solve this issue.

Also can someone elabrate on how onDataChange works , does it get called when all the values at the node are retrieved or 'some' of the data is retrieved ?

Should one use AsyncTask in such a scenario when retrieving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to delete fanned out data from many locations.

When you perform a multi-location `update()` such as this, the security rules for all nodes are checked before any of the changes are made. So (unless there is a bug in the way Firebase enforces these specific security rules), the disconnect can't be caused by security rules.

If your other nodes are updated, but `/user-subscriptions/" + userIdKey + "//" + mChannelKey` is not deleted, then you are likely not getting any children in `dataSnapshot` (and thus not passing them in `delChannelMap`). You'll want to run through the code in a debugger to verify that.

Whenever troubleshooting issues such as this, be sure to handle `onCancelled()`. It is the easiest way to get an indication of why an operation failed. Although I don't think it will execute here (after all, the write operation seems to succeed), I recommend you [attach a completion callback to `setValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue):

```
ref.setValue("My new value", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Throwing an exception like this ensures that it will be very difficult to overlook such an error next time.

Comment: Thanks Frank I will get back to you if the error remains.

Answer (score 2):

1. `onDataChange` gives you **all the underlying child nodes at a single time** whenever there is a change in the child nodes.
2. Firebase when retrieve data it uses a different thread to perform its task so no need of using `AsyncTask`.
3. the problem in your code maybe due to this `String userIdKey=childSnapshot.getKey();`...where the `childSnapshot.getKey();` is not firing the data u want.. You should check in LOGCAT if data is retrieved correctly.

If it is not clear yet please add Json Data of your database so that it could be easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: For #1: `onDataChange()` fires immediately for the current value. But it indeed does fire with the *complete* node. Firebase *never* fires for partial nodes.